# How to access JSON Object.$$state.value?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Warning: I'm going to sound like I have no idea what I'm talking about here, because I kind of don't. I'm in the process of self-learning Javascript and AngularJS through a lot of trial and error coding.

I have some javascript code (hesitant to copy here because it's a mess) that returns an Object with the following structure:
[image]

What I want to save to a variable is the object corresponding to Object.$$state.value in the picture. This object has username, hash and salt, which are what I care about. I don't know what all the other stuff like $$state are or how they got there.

However, if I do this (let's call the main Object "whatIHave"):

```
var whatIWant = whatIHave.$$state.value;
```

this does not work. whatIWant is null.

Does anyone recognize what's going on here? What is $$state, how did it get there, and how can I extract the value I want?

Comment: $state is apparently an angular object. I think this is the correct reference here: [$state](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state).  However, your question is difficult to answer without any code to put it in context.  Share some ugly code ... it's okay. Oh, and thanks for the laugh too ... funnest post I've read tonight.

Comment: At least share enough context code to see where you are logging this from

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So that is a promise. You need to do something like:

```
whatIHave.then(function(whatIWant) {
  // Work here
});
```

I highly recommend you to research what a promise is (like this [link](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html))

If you're curious enough, about what is that `$$state` and what is that `value`, I will explain a bit:

The promises have a `$$state` and there angular saves all the callback functions you want to call in a `pending` array (all those function you registered with `.then` like I explained before).

It also have the status: resolved (1) and rejected (2)

Finally, when you `resolve` or `reject` the promise, the value you pass when doing that, is saved in `value`.

You're trying to cheat in here, because when you try to access that `value`, it could be not there yet (that is what `async` is all about).

So the idea is learning the basic of promises, learning how to work with them and then use your `whatIHave` correctly.